# SQL - Never select another record with the same id sorted by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I want to select only the top 1 record per ID in the result sorted by date so there won't be another record with the same ID.

Here's a more detailed example: the date is formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
+----------+-------+-------------+
| Id       | name  | date        |
+----------+-------+-------------+
| 1        | a     | 2019-01-01  |
| 1        | a2    | 2019-01-02  |
| 2        | b     | 2019-01-01  |
| 3        | c     | 2019-01-02  |
| 3        | c2    | 2019-01-01  |
| 4        | d     | 2019-01-01  |
+----------+-------+-------------+
```

And the result I want to have is something like this:

```
+----------+-------+-------------+
| Id       | name  | date        |
+----------+-------+-------------+
| 1        | a2    | 2019-01-02  |
| 2        | b     | 2019-01-01  |
| 3        | c     | 2019-01-02  |
| 4        | d     | 2019-01-01  |
+----------+-------+-------------+
```

So I want to only get one record per `ID` which is the latest record.

How can I achieve this in SQL?

Thanks for those who will help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make use of `row_number()` to partition by `Id` and order by `date` desc

```
select *
from   (
          select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by [Id] order by [date] desc)
          from   yourtable
       ) d
where  d.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use sub query with `GROUP BY`  `MAX` for each id as below

Note: please don't use keywords as column name

```
declare @table as table(Id INT, [name] varchar(50), [date] date)
insert into @table values
(1,'a',     '2019-01-01'),
(1,'a2',    '2019-01-02'),
(2,'b',     '2019-01-01'),
(3,'c',     '2019-01-02'),
(3,'c2',    '2019-01-01'),
(4,'d',     '2019-01-01')

SELECT t.*
FROM @table t
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX([date]) AS [date] FROM @table GROUP BY id) t1 ON t1.[date] = t.[date]
    AND t1.id = t.id
ORDER BY t.id
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Id  name    date
1   a2      2019-01-02
2   b       2019-01-01
3   c       2019-01-02
4   d       2019-01-01
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the combination of Id and date is always unique.  The question did not specifically state that this was true.

Comment: Thanks! This also works! but I like the partition trick that @Squirrel used! Yes, I only use keywords as column names as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `GROUP BY ID` and select `MAX(date)` to get this:

```
SELECT a.Id, b.name, a.date
FROM
(SELECT Id, MAX(date) AS max_date FROM
 <your_table_name>
 GROUP BY Id) a
INNER JOIN
<your_table_name> b
ON
a.Id = b.Id AND
a.max_date = b.date
```